# Catch last command error message in Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, error-messaging

I'm trying to understand if there is a way to catch the error message from the last command that was executed in the shell. I aim to catch any error (outputted from shell scripts/python/etc..) and I wonder if there is a single place where the error messages are written. I'm building a script that tries to parse error message from the last command and find solutions and I would like that the script will run after the command was already executed and that the last error will be parsed.

Thanks!

Comment: The only place where a not redirected error message stays is the terminal buffer, together with all other output. You will have a hard time to access that, and even harder to separate it from non-error output.